# Plymouth custom splash shows Debian Logo

Tags: debian, plymouth

I have managed to install a custom splash screen for Debian (buster) using plymouth. However once installed and rebooted I noticed that my OEM logo was in the way so i disabled it with UseFirmwareBackground=False and added a background-tile.png file (blank black image) to the theme. This fixed the OEM issue but now I am left with this Debian logo.

How can i remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I was looking for was Watermark settings.

Managed to fix it by moving it out of screen by adding these two lines to the [themename].plymouth file

```
WatermarkHorizontalAlignment=1.5
WatermarkVerticalAlignment=1.5
```